# javascript/jquery how to set more than one attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this for loop which will append options to that "optlist"; the value will be set to manSel[i][0] and the text to manSel[i][1]; I would also like to set the attribute selected="selected" to all of them. Can I do that in the same loop or should I iterate again throug the options and add that attribute to each one of them. Thanks in advance!

```
for(var i = 0 ; i<manSel.length; i++){
  optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', manSel[i][0]).text(manSel[i][1]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i<manSel.length; i++){
  optlist.append($('<option/>').attr({value: manSel[i][0], selected: "selected"}).text(manSel[i][1]));
}
```

Comment: What on earth has this got to do with jQuery enumerable @pkurek?

Answer (score 2):

you could use this

```
optlist.append($('<option selected="selected"/>').attr('value', manSel[i][0]).text(manSel[i][1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

To add more attributes use an object, this is very well explained in the jQuery Docs, I mean this is [pretty basic stuff to find](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$ele.attr({ href: '', src: '' })
```

In any case `value` has a special method `val()`:

```
$ele.val(value)
```

And `selected` is a property is meant to be used with `prop()`.

```
$ele.prop('selected', true)
```